# Purpose of special railway transport wagons?

Tags: transportation

What's the purpose of the special railway transport wagons shown in the photograph?

[image: railway wagons]

Comment: Any more detail? Country? View of other side? That shape tends to be so they clear tunnels...

Comment: Suggest you move this to a Trainspotters specialty group.